# Parameters in initialized const

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks

I'm in a situation where I want to dispatch an event in Redux. I'm noticing that defining `const` in Javascript is a little bit confusing. When I'm trying to add a parameter directly to the `useAppDispatch` function, the linter marks an error.

```
import { PlusCircleIcon } from "@heroicons/react/20/solid";
import React from "react";
import { useAppDispatch } from "../../store/hooks";

const OptionsPanelAddAction = ():JSX.Element => {
  const handleOnClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>):void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    useAppDispatch({type: "ADD_CLICKED"}); ---> Expected 0 arguments, but got 1
  }

  return (
    <div className="bg-white m-4 p-2 drop-shadow-sm flex justify-center">
      <div>
        <a><PlusCircleIcon className="h-6 w-6" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default OptionsPanelAddAction;
```

But when I put the `dispatch` function in a const I'm able to add an parameter:

```
import { PlusCircleIcon } from "@heroicons/react/20/solid";
import React from "react";
import { useAppDispatch } from "../../store/hooks";

const OptionsPanelAddAction = ():JSX.Element => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const handleOnClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>):void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({type: "ADD_CLICKED"}); ---> No Error!
  }

  return (
    <div className="bg-white m-4 p-2 drop-shadow-sm flex justify-center">
      <div>
        <a><PlusCircleIcon className="h-6 w-6" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default OptionsPanelAddAction;
```

Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## About `const` declarations

`const dispatch = useDispatch()` isn't storing a `const` reference to the `useDispatch` function, it's calling the `useDispatch` function and storing a `const` reference of its ***return value***, the `dispatch` function.

In Javascript (*and Typescript*) declaring a variable `const` only means the variable can't be reassigned a value, though it can be mutated.

```
const foo = {
  bar: "bizz"
};

foo = { // <-- error, can't reassign foo
  bar: "buzz"
};

foo.bar = "buzz"; // <-- OK, we can mutate the foo object
```

In React we declare component variables `const` to indicate they will not be reassigned a value for the duration of the React component render cycle, i.e. the reference won't change during the component render.

## About the `useAppDispatch` hook

`useAppDispatch` is a React hook that must be called ***on its own*** first prior to returning the `dispatch` function. The `useAppDispatch` function does not consume any arguments. The action object is passed to the `dispatch` function, not the hook.

### Doesn't work

```js
useAppDispatch({ type: "ADD_CLICKED" });
```

### Does work

```js
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

...

dispatch({ type: "ADD_CLICKED" });
```

While you *could* try something like `useAppDispatch()({ type: "ADD_CLICKED" });` I wouldn't recommend this at all as it is not a common use pattern and likely hurts readability/maintainability and may even break the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) given where you might be trying to call it.

Answer (score 0):

`useAppDispatch` is a hook which returns a reference to the dispatch function from the Redux store.  here is the [doc](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch)

you have to call the hook and then you can use the reference like this:

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
dispatch({type: "ADD_CLICKED"});
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the reply. I want to understand the "why"! Is that syntactic sugar? Some magic under the hood? For me its not really easy to unterstand..

Comment: @Felix It's just a function that returns a function. There's no magic. You can easily write such a higher order function yourself.

Comment: thanks @unmitigated. But what happens with the parameter? I thought const only contains the reference...

Comment: useAppDispatch just return a new function, if you don't want to store this ref in const, then you can use like this `useAppDispatch()({type: "ADD_CLICKED"})`